# Akka Stream Kafka: No configuration setting found for key 'kafka-clients'

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

I'm trying to create a simple prototype using [Alpakka Kafka connector (Akka Stream Kafka)](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/home.html).

When running the application I get the following error:

```
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'kafka-clients'
```

I have the following code in `./src/main/scala/App.scala`:

```
import akka.Done
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.kafka.ProducerSettings
import akka.kafka.scaladsl.Producer
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, Materializer}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

import scala.concurrent.Future

object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello from producer")

    implicit val system = ActorSystem("fakeProducer")
    implicit val materializer: Materializer = ActorMaterializer()

    val config = system.settings.config // ConfigFactory.load()

    val producerSettings =
      ProducerSettings(config, new StringSerializer, new StringSerializer)
      .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")

    val done: Future[Done] =
      Source(1 to 100)
        .map(_.toString)
        .map(value => new ProducerRecord[String, String]("test-basic-numbers", value))
        .runWith(Producer.plainSink(producerSettings))


    println("Done")
  }
}
```

The following `build.sbt`:

```
name := "test-akka-stream"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream-kafka" % "0.21.1"
```

I run the app using `sbt run`. I have not configured any uber/assembly jar.

I'm probably missing something obvious but I cannot see it ... I suspect there is some problem with akka dependencies.

### UPDATE

As suggested by @terminally-chill calling `ProducerSettings(system, new StringSerializer, new StringSerializer)` (passing `ActorSystem` instead of a configuration) solve the problem. I just don't understand if this is by design or a bug.

### UPDATE 2

I have create a [github issue](https://github.com/akka/alpakka-kafka/issues/515) that is already been fixed. Now documentation is more accurate and explain the correct way to create the `ProducerSettings`/`ConsumerSettings`.

```
val config = system.settings.config.getConfig("akka.kafka.producer")
val producerSettings =
      ProducerSettings(config, new StringSerializer, new StringSerializer)
      .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
```

or you can pass the `ActorSystem` as explained above.

Comment: Did you define the Kafka consumer config. as outlined here - https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/consumer.html

Comment: Where is your `application.conf` file? and what does it look like?

Comment: @terminally-chill I have tried to create `src/main/resources/application.conf` with the same content defined [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/producer.html). But the error is the same.

Comment: @Nio For now I just want to try producer (I just want to write to a kafka topic). I don't need a consumer config right?

Comment: Do you get the same exception if you do not pass a config object in to the ProducerSettings apply method? It should take  (ActorSystem, Serializer, Serializer)

Comment: @terminally-chill No, `ProducerSettings(ActorSystem, Serializer, Serializer)` overload works! Thanks! Do you think it is by design? Or a bug?

Comment: @DavideIcardi please take a look at my answer below. `system.settings.config` is actually not being read from your `application.conf`, because it was never passed in to the ActorSystem when being created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for noticing and filing an issue in the Alpakka Kafka connector project.
The documentation is now updated: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/producer.html

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @terminally-chill and @murray-todd-williams for your answers. I have made some further researches and I try to summarize here:

Both `ConsumerSettings` and `ProducerSettings` have `apply` functions that take a `Config` (see [here](https://github.com/akka/alpakka-kafka/blob/e5c398e5bcf740b8877a94f93eca5e852e93cf01/core/src/main/scala/akka/kafka/ConsumerSettings.scala#L47)) or an `ActorSystem` (see [here](https://github.com/akka/alpakka-kafka/blob/e5c398e5bcf740b8877a94f93eca5e852e93cf01/core/src/main/scala/akka/kafka/ConsumerSettings.scala#L33)).

The problem is that when using `ActorSystem` the code is:

```
val config = system.settings.config.getConfig("akka.kafka.consumer")
apply(config, keyDeserializer, valueDeserializer) // call the other overload
```

while when using `Config` the code is:

```
val properties = ConfigSettings.parseKafkaClientsProperties(config.getConfig("kafka-clients"))
```

So when passing a config directly the code search for a `kafka-clients` property, instead when passing an `ActorSystem` the code check for a `akka.kafka.consumer/akka.kafka.producer`.

Finally consider that when creating an `ActorSystem` instance by default most of the settings are loaded from an embedded `reference.conf` file and merged with your `application.conf` file if present. More info [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/configuration.html#configuration).
So basically the only required property to set is usually the `bootstrap.servers`.

So you can now understand why when using `system.settings.config` the code doesn't work. This config instance has loaded `reference.conf` (with all the defaults, see [here](https://github.com/akka/alpakka-kafka/blob/master/core/src/main/resources/reference.conf)) and custom `application.conf`. The `kafka-clients` property is inside `akka.kafka.consumer/akka.kafka.producer`, but the code check directly for `kafka-clients`.

Some possible solutions:

- Directly pass the `ActorSystem` using the other overload
- Pass the right section using `system.settings.config.getConfig("akka.kafka.consumer")`
- Manually construct a `Config` instance with the `kafka-clients` section

For me the problem is that the official documentation provided [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/consumer.html) doesn't mention these differences and the example provided are not complete and/or not precise. Probably for an Akka expert this is clear, but for new developers this can be very confusing.

I have created a more "ready to use" example [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/davideicardi/ff914afe01cd8db97bae16a533d21fc8) and open an [issue](https://github.com/akka/alpakka-kafka/issues/515).

Comment: Thanks for the gist. I'm slowly evolving my own "hello world" consumer (I did get things fundamentally to work yesterday, but I'm evolving functionality bit-by-bit.) but this will help me get the configuration stuff working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I keep all my config in the AkkaSystem instance. I don't use Alpakka for Kafka, but have based many of my implementations off the source code.

Load the typesafe config object with `val config = ConfigFactory.load()` and then pass `config` in to `val system = ActorSystem("fakeProducer", config)`.

Finally, pass `system.settings.config` to `ProducerSettings`.

Your current code does not pass any settings, because you have not loaded the config in to your Akka system. Your `val config = system.settings.config` is referencing an empty config, which does not have a kafka-clients section (best guess).

Comment: Thanks for your info, I have made some further investigation, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50943486/209727

Answer (score 1):

I think I've run into the same issue you did (at almost the exact same time) although I'm trying to create a basic 'hello world' Kafka consumer instead of a producer. I'm guessing you were just going through the documentation in the [Alpakka Kafka connector documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/home.html) and were following the example where they first define

```
val config = system.settings.config
```

and then pass it into the new ConsumerSettings object. I'm going to guess there's a defect with the online documentation, but I'm new enough to Akka Streams (this is my first attempt to learn by example) that I'm not qualified to figure out exactly what's right or wrong.

I had tried to create and application.conf file, and then do the ConfigFactory.load() and then manually pass that to the ActorSystem upon creation, and then I passed that system to the ConsumerSettings constructor, and the error about the missing "kafka-clients" went away, but apparently I didn't have to even do that. As you said, just passing the 'system' variable instead of the 'config' variable does the trick.

Hope this helps anyone who is similarly fumbling around in the dark. I've got to say, for all the buzz there is around Akka Streams, it seems like there's a real lack of documentation out there. I might have to write a blog article once I get this stuff figured out!

Comment: Thanks for your info, I have made some further investigation, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50943486/209727 . I completely agree with you, the documentation is quite bad.

Comment: Please help out and make the documentation better! File your suggestions as issues or even better as pull requests in the [Github project](https://github.com/akka/alpakka-kafka)